# Replace a part of an expression with a value from a variable

Tags: r

I would like to write an expression in *R* where I can modify some part of it depending on some other variable. For example, let's say that I want to create a lot of new columns in my data frame using the following basic expression:

```
MyDataFrame$ColumnNumber1 <- 33
```

If I wanted to create a lot of these, I could just type them out explicitly

```
MyDataFrame$ColumnNumber2 <- 52
MyDataFrame$ColumnNumber3 <- 12
...
```

and so on. However, this would be impractical if I have to many of them. Therefore, I'd like to have some way of replacing a part of the expression with something that's generated through a variable. Let's for example say that there was an operator `Input()` that would do this. Then I could write a function looking like this:

```
for(i in 1:1000)
{
    MyDataFrame$ColumnNumberInput(i) <- 32*i
}
```

where the `Input(i)` part would be replaced with whatever number the counter were at at the moment, which in turn would generate an expression.

I now that I can do this by using:

```
eval(parse(text=paste("MyDataFrame$","Column","Number","1","<- 32*i",sep="")))
```

but this gets impossible to use if the expression is too complicated, long, or have other things like this nested inside of it.

Comment: why do you want to proceed this way?? you can simply do `do.call(cbind, list(df, lapply(1:10, function(u) setNames(data.frame(u*32),u))))`

Comment: `MyDataFrame[, paste0("ColumnNumber", i) <- 52`? It's not obvious what exactly you are trying to achieve. There might be a better approach.

Comment: There are occasions where using the `[[]]` operator, which is what I think @Speldose wants here, is helpful. Literate programming, where ease of maintenance and readability are given priority over efficiency, come to mind. That said, this approach does lend itself to "speaking R with a C accent," and thus should be used with caution. If you don't need to prioritize readability, consider the approach suggested by @ColonelBeauvel.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel That would work for this specific case, but I find it less readable than @JustinFletcher's solution. Also, I was on the hunt for something more general (for example, what if I want to use some kind of terminal input to name my columns?) and my example was just a narrow example. @Roland's solution might have worked for what I was trying to do in this case, but what I'm really after is a general way of generating text that becomes a part of an expression which then is evaluated. Something like "\Input(x)" is ALWAYS replaced with `x` no matter where it's placed.

Comment: Work with the language, not against it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[[]]`:

```
for(i in 1:1000)
{
    MyDataFrame[[i]] <- 32*i
}
```

`[[]]` is the programmatic equivalent of `$`.

You may then reference the data structure as:

```
MyDataFrame[[14]] <- MyDataObjFourteen
MyDataFrame$14
MyDataFrame[[14]]
```

You could also use strings, like so:

```
MyDataFrame[["SomeString"]] <- 32
MyDataFrame$SomeString
# 32
```

EDIT 1:

To do something similar, in a more general way try:

```
assign("someArbitraryString", 3)
someArbitraryString
# 3
as.name(someArbitraryString)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for my specific problem. I'm still on the look for a more general way to do this though (see my comment on my original question).